# Looking for form/survey creator that can show hidden questions in response to “Checkbox” questions

Tags: windows, forms, survey

I was attempting to make a form with either google forms or microsoft forms, but neither seem to have the type of branching feature I'm looking for. I know about the feature which sends users to different sections based on their answer, but I need a form that shows otherwise hidden follow up questions on the same page, and can show several follow up questions in response to questions allowing multiple answers ("Checkbox" questions). [This older post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100279/conditional-branching-in-google-forms-checkbox) better describes what I'm trying to achieve.

It shouldn't be in a format that requires answerers to commit to their multiple choices. The idea is that they could select one answer, see the follow up, and de-select that answer if they don't like any of the follow up options. Then when they decide which follow up option groups they prefer, they should be able to choose as many as they want. I’m only looking for free programs. Preferably one that works on windows computers.